# How to use all map types in google map

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I want to use all map types of google map.But i am only able to set once at a time.Is there anyway so we can set all map types for single map.

For now i am using roadmap.how i can use all map types.

Here is my code:

```
   var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        geo.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var myLatLngh = results[0].geometry.location;

                var myOptions = {
                    center: myLatLngh,
                    zoom: 12,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLngh,
                    title: address
                });

                marker.setMap(map);
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>Company Address</b><br/> " + address });
                infowindow.open(map, marker);









            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the var myOptions add de following options: **mapTypeControl** and **mapTypeControlOptions**

```
var myOptions = {
                center: myLatLngh,
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}          
            };
```